# Computer Vision - Figuring out what angle the camera is pointing to as it moves around?

Tags: video, video-processing, computer-vision

I sometimes attach a video camera to my motorcycle helmet and ride around. Obviously I move my head a little bit, and go around corners, etc. Here's a [sample, edited video to give you an idea](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUk0DfRMa3o). Except the raw originals will all be in one sequence (no cuts).

Given a video like this, is it possible to figure out / make a good guess as to which direction each frame is pointing, relative to the previous frame, and hence figure out, globally which way each frame points?

I figure this should be possible using feature detection (SIFT?) and/or the same type of thing used in image stabilization? But I have no experience with computer vision, so I'm not sure if this is impossible, has been done before, or if there's a library for it already. Hence this question.

I have lots of Python experience and some gstreamer and C experience. Open source solutions are preferable, and "runs on linux" is a requirement. I'd be tempted to code this up myself, but I don't know if there's any maths/algorithms done already (if so, what?)

Comment: You could search for "structure from motion". It's a bit more complex problem, though: it tries to reconstruct the camera's motion, orientation and the depth of the tracked features.

Comment: Question is way too generic, and likely not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Google search for "SfM", "SaM", "SLAM", etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to implement a full structure from motion algorithm (which is a big task), here's an idea I would try:

First track interest points from one frame to the next. SIFT or SURF is probably a good start. Most of the interest points don't move very far, and once you have processed the first two frames, you have a good estimate where each interest point will be in the next frame, so this should be possible.

Once you have feature correspondences between two frames, the movement of each feature point is (approximately) a sum of two components: One component away from the vanishing point (that is, the direction of motion of the bike) and one component that's identical for each point (the camera's orientation change).

[image]

Mathematically speaking, that means point p's location at time t1 is:

[image]

where v is the vanishing point, d is the speed of movement away from the vanishing point in the image (depends on the distance of the object from the observer and the speed of the bike) and m is the camera's motion. That's 2*n equations and 4+n unknowns for n points, meaning if you have 4 or more points, you can find an (approximate) solution.